# To add body and fixture to a ring in Box2d

Tags: box2d, physics, fixtures

How do i add body and fixture to a ring. 
Eg: http://marinestore.co.uk/Merchant2/graphics/00000001/round_ring.jpg

Answer (score 3):

A ring is a concave shape. Physics engines can only work with convex shapes. So you would have to split up the ring into multiple concave shapes forming a ring. Your best bet is to use a proper tool like [PhysicsEditor](http://www.physicseditor.de/) that helps you create such shapes.